# Why does not work apache host config?

Tags: php, apache, server

I have created separated conf file in directory: `conf.d` with the following settings:

```
ServerName www.signal.com
ServerAdmin signal@gmail.com

<VirtualHost 138.201.171.252:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/signal/html
ErrorLog logs/signal-error_log
CustomLog logs/signal-access_log common

<Directory />
Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/signal/html>
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I open IP address: 138.201.171.252:80 I get Apache test page instead of index.php, but when I call `index.php` directly like as: `138.201.171.252:80/index.php` I get content of file `index.php` as text in browser.

Comment: The more information you provide, the easier it will be for someone to help you. What OS are you using? Where did you get Apache? Where did you get PHP? What version of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. How do you make index.php load as the index?

See [DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html).

2. How do you make php executed?

Is PHP installed? You can test it by running

```
$ php -v
```

which should give you the php version information.

If it *is* installed, you need to enable `mod_php`. What Apache version are you running?

Comment: "Is PHP installed? You can test it by running" --- having the php executable does not mean the webserver SAPI is installed. They frequently are delivered in separate independent OS packages.

Comment: @zerkms You are right, but it's a first step. It seems like Bedouin isn't interested anyway.

Comment: Yep, always is disappointing when no feedback from the OP :-) +1'd you for your attempt though.

Comment: My PHP is: PHP 5.6.27, and I added DirectoryIndex in confid

Comment: @Bedouin What part does not work? Is index.php loading now? What Linux distribution are you using?